# Ramda: How to minimize computing resources by currying, filtering and mapping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, currying, ramda.js

I'm building a React app using Ramda. I'm still new to functional programming (~ two months in).

I have a list of contacts like this:

```
const contacts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Sven',
    lastName: 'Hillstedt',
    city: 'Aachen',
    company: '',
    position: 'Student',
    group: 'friends',
    tendency: 'maintain'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'David',
  // ...
];
```

Given a string I need to filter this (very long, 10.000-100.000) list. But I only need to take into account the keys `firstName`, `lastName`, `city`, `company` and `position`. There is an array containing these:

```
const FIRST_NAME = 'firstName';
const LAST_NAME = 'lastName';
const CITY = 'city';
const COMPANY = 'company';
const POSITION = 'position';

export const stringFields = [FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CITY, COMPANY, POSITION];
```

Now, using Ramda I wrote the following function(s) that takes a `string` and a list of contacts, maps over the contacts` keys picking the relevant ones and lowercasing them and then returns the filtered contacts:

```
import { any, filter, includes, map, pick, pipe, toLower, values } from 'ramda';

const contactIncludesValue = value =>
  pipe(
    pick(stringFields),
    map(toLower),
    values,
    any(includes(value))
  );

const filterContactsByValue = value => filter(contactIncludesValue(value));
```

As you can see this code is messy (even thought it is way prettier than doing it imperatively). I curry `value =>` many times, which feels unoptimal. I'm also questioning, whether this code only iterates over the contacts once and if it is efficient.

How would you filter and map (pick only the relevant keys + `lowerCase`) a large list of contacts without iterating over it twice or more? Is there a way to avoid my currying and write this cleaner?

Comment: Every performance optimisation should start with a benchmark and/or profiling. Please provide the results of those.

Comment: @zerkms It depends, in the browser on my MacBook Pro this is barely noticeable, but on an android phone you could see a lap, if you iterate over the list multiple times.

Comment: If you don't have a baseline - you cannot prove the "improved" solution actually improved anything. If you like to waste time on random things and hope that it magically would improve anything - good on you, have fun :-)

Comment: For example in your case, there is a good chance the problem is not actually with iterating many times, but with allocating tons of temporary arrays and searching through them linearly. But hey, please improve the number of loops (because you _guessed_ so, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to respond to here.

- Even if the comments were slightly snarky, @zerkms has it right.  It makes little sense to try performance optimization unless you know that the code actually *has* poor performance, especially if it makes the code harder to write or maintain.
- You do not curry `value =>` multiple times.  It's curried only up front, and the partial application of your value happens once per filtering of the list.
- You only iterate your contacts a single time.  But inside each one is a call to `any` over your list of fields.  This one does an early return if it finds a match, so it's not trivial to calculate the number of calls, but it's probably `O(m * n)` where `m` is the number of fields and `n` the number of contacts.

This version of your code is slightly more condensed.  You might or might not find it more readable:

```
const contactIncludesValue = value =>
  pipe(
    props(stringFields),
    map(toLower),
    any(includes(value))
  );

const filterContactsByValue = pipe(contactIncludesValue, filter);
```

Note that `props` is more convenient than `pick(...) -> values`, and the intermediate `map(toLower)` works just as well afterward.

Comment: Perhaps `map(toLower)` could be removed if `any(includes(value))` read `any(eqBy(toLower, value))` instead. This would mean two things: 1) you don't need to lowercase everything beforehand *(very small improvement)* and 2) `value` doesn't need to be lowercased itself.

Answer (score 2):

> How would you filter and map (pick only the relevant keys + lowerCase) a large list of contacts without iterating over it twice or more? Is there a way to avoid my currying and write this cleaner?

If you need to filter *AND* transform your data in one go, I don't see how you could do this using `filter` alone.

For example, this won't keep `a` and transform it:

```js
const list = [
  {a: 'foo'},
  {b: 'bar'}
];

console.log(

  filter(pipe(map(toUpper), has('a')), list)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {filter, pipe, map, toUpper, has} = R;</script>
```

For that you need to either use `reduce` or a transducer.

Here's a solution using a transducer. In this example:

1. Only work with objects which `a` property is equal to `1`.
2. On `b` property, add `10`
3. Then pick `b`

```js
const list = [
  {a: 1, b: 2},
  {a: 2, b: 20},
  {a: 1, b: 3},
  {a: 2, b: 30},
  {a: 1, b: 4},
  {a: 2, b: 40},
];

console.log(

into([],
  compose(
    filter(propEq('a', 1)),
    map(over(lensProp('b'), add(10))),
    map(pick(['b']))
  ),
  list)
  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {into, compose, filter, propEq, map, pick, over, lensProp, add} = R;</script>
```

The nice thing about using transducers, is that it decouples the logic for producing the result (an array) from the logic for transforming data.

`into([])` tells Ramda that you're producing an array and therefore whatever comes out of your `compose` chain, will need to be appended to it.

`into('')` tells Ramda that you're producing a string. Your `compose` chain only needs to return a string. `into` will take care of concatenating it to the final result:

```js
const list = [
  {a: 1, b: 2},
  {a: 2, b: 20},
  {a: 1, b: 3},
  {a: 2, b: 30},
  {a: 1, b: 4},
  {a: 2, b: 40},
];

console.log(

into('',
  compose(
    filter(propEq('a', 1)),
    map(over(lensProp('b'), add(10))),
    map(prop('b'))
  ),
  list)
  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {into, compose, filter, propEq, map, over, lensProp, add, prop} = R;</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`R.innerJoin` would surely represent the most concise way of writing it, but I'm not sure about its time complexity.

```js
const filter = value => R.innerJoin(
  // you may lowercase, etc... here
  (record, prop) => R.propEq(prop, value, record),
  R.__,
  ['firstName', 'lastName', 'city', 'company', 'position'],
);

const onlySven = filter('Sven');
const onlyGiuseppe = filter('Giuseppe');

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Sven',
    lastName: 'Hillstedt',
    city: 'Aachen',
    company: '',
    position: 'Student',
    group: 'friends',
    tendency: 'maintain'
  },
  // ...
];

console.log('Giuseppe', onlyGiuseppe(data));
console.log('Sven', onlySven(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```